# How to make hidden text appear when scrolling down to a certain part of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-animations, display

I have added some animations to my website and I want them to appear when a user scrolls down to the middle part of the sections.  I have found a way to do this with some old code from a "top of page button".  It works pretty well but when on more narrow screens, **it adjusts/shakes the page and it looks weird, plus I believe if I add more to the page it will require me to adjust the pixel amount.  Like I said, the issue happens when the screen is responsive. Is there a better way to do all of this?**
https://codepen.io/drxl/pen/JjNVbgP
Here is the JS I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var downscroll = 450;
    var timeLength = 500;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > downscroll) {
            $('.about__title, .portrait, .bottom-text-animation').fadeIn(timeLength);
        } else {
            $('.about__title, .portrait, .bottom-text-animation').fadeOut(timeLength);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: The codepen link isn't working.

Comment: Forgot to save, try now

Comment: still your code rendering nothing inside frame. Also you didn't add `jQuery` cdn.

Comment: Try again, if it doesn't work I can just give you the entire website, its not that big just one page (it's actually my portfolio iste)

Comment: Your code still required a lot of errors to be fixed. I just couldn't make out anything from it.

Comment: OK, at this point I will just have to put the code up on my github and you can look at if you want https://github.com/Drxl95/PortfolioWebsite-2/tree/main

Comment: I just can't copy paste your entire code and will work on that. Atleast host it somewhere like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and don't worry its free.

Comment: It is live, It just wasn;t finished.  I will give you the link.  Give me a sec and I will upload the  chamges (I have been working on it)

Comment: https://www.robertuebelhor.com/    it's the About Me sections where I have that JS code

Comment: Now I understand what you want you want to show the the text after `Download my resume` button when the scrolling reaches near to it for that I would suggest you to look [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) it is wonderfull animate on scroll library it will help you alot.

Comment: Ok but real quick shrink the wndow down (or go into the dev tools and look at one of the tablets/phones and then scroll down to the about me section, notice how it messes with the background, how do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: IntersectionObserver may help you rather than needing to sense the scrolling event all the time.

Comment: Instead of using `min-height` use `height` only. It will work or solve your problem. Let me know.

Comment: I think it works! I need to make it responsive and change some sizes/fonts so the text doesn't run off the section!

Comment: Actually it works but now the responsive part is broken,  the page doesn't expand wit the text/

Comment: Yeah I encountered the same. Instead of `display` property use `opacity` or `visibility`.

Comment: The elements don't show up if I use that stuff.